# Add subtract values through functions and append data to a list on for loop

Tags: python

Non computer science guy question here, but I am trying to make a program that can compile numbers based off of a schedule of events (hopefully this all makes sense).

Schedule is a nested dictionary:

```
schedule = {

        '0:00':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '0:30':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '1:00':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '1:30':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '2:00':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '2:30':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '3:00':  {'Floor1': 'ON', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '3:30':  {'Floor1': 'ON', 'Floor2': 'ON', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '4:00':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'ON', 'Floor3': 'ON', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '4:30':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'ON', 'Floor4': 'ON', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '5:00':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'ON', 'Floor5': 'ON', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},  
        '5:30':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'ON', 'Floor6': 'ON', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '6:00':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'ON', 'Floor7': 'ON', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '6:30':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'ON', 'Floor8': 'ON' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '7:00':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'ON' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'},
        '7:30':  {'Floor1': 'OFF', 'Floor2': 'OFF', 'Floor3': 'OFF', 'Floor4': 'OFF', 'Floor5': 'OFF', 'Floor6': 'OFF', 'Floor7': 'OFF', 'Floor8': 'OFF' , 'Floor9': 'OFF'}   
       }
```

And I can loop through each key of the `schedule` dictionary that will print the time/key:

```
for key, value in schedule.items():
    print(key)
```

prints:

```
0:00
0:30
1:00
1:30
2:00
2:30
3:00
3:30
4:00
4:30
5:00
5:30
6:00
6:30
7:00
7:30
```

I was curious to see if I could create a program that could loop through each key and sum up what power consumption would be give the time. Sum floor1,floor2,floor4,etc...

A lot code here, sorry any tips how to do this better greatly appreciated... but if I run this

```
import time


def floor1(run='OFF'):
    kW = 0 
    if run == 'ON':
        return 47.1  
    else:
        return 0

def floor2(run='OFF'):
    kW = 0 
    if run == 'ON':
        return 31.8
    else:
        return 0

def floor4(run='OFF'):
    kW = 0 
    if run == 'ON':
        return 45.69  
    else:
        return 0

def floor5(run='OFF'):
    kW = 0 
    if run == 'ON':
        return 77.2 
    else:
        return 0

def floor6(run='OFF'):
    kW = 0 
    if run == 'ON':
        return 36.6 
    else:
        return 0

def floor7(run='OFF'):
    kW = 0 
    if run == 'ON':
        return 59.9 
    else:
        return 0

def floor8(run='OFF'):
    kW = 0 
    if run == 'ON':
        return 85.2
    else:
        return 0


def floor9(run='OFF'):
    kW = 0 
    if run == 'ON':
        return 61.1  
    else:
        return 0
    
    
    
    
total_computed_data = []


for i in range(len(schedule.keys())):

    this_loop_data = []
    
    for key, value in schedule.items():
    
        floor1 = floor1(schedule[key]['Floor1'])
        print(floor1)
        this_loop_data.append(floor1)

        floor2 = floor2(schedule[key]['Floor2'])
        print(floor2)
        this_loop_data.append(floor2)
        
        floor4 = floor4(schedule[key]['Floor4'])
        print(floor4)
        this_loop_data.append(floor4)
        
        floor5 = floor5(schedule[key]['Floor5'])
        print(floor5)
        this_loop_data.append(floor5)

        floor6 = floor6(schedule[key]['Floor6'])
        print(floor6)
        this_loop_data.append(floor6)
        
        floor7 = floor7(schedule[key]['Floor7'])
        print(floor7)
        this_loop_data.append(floor7)
        
        floor8 = floor8(schedule[key]['Floor8'])
        print(floor8)
        this_loop_data.append(floor8)
        
        floor9 = floor9(schedule[key]['Floor9'])
        print(floor9)
        this_loop_data.append(floor9)

        total_computed_data.append(sum(this_loop_data))
        time.sleep(1)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-96fa74c3978a> in <module>
     71     for key, value in schedule.items():
     72 
---> 73         floor1 = floor1(schedule[key]['Floor1'])
     74         print(floor1)
     75         this_loop_data.append(floor1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

My idea was to be able to modify the `schedule` dictionary for different simulations and view/plot different variations of the `total_computed_data`

Comment: You override the name of the function with its own return value (which is an int...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this, I suggest adding `print()` statements to see what is going on. For example, you can add `print(floor1)` to your code to see its value.

You will quickly find that you are using the name `floor1` for two different purposes. The first time the loop executes, `floor1` is a function. But then you immediately assign the name `floor1` to the return value of that function. Now the next time the loop iterates, it attempts to treat that value as a function and call it with parameter. As you can imagine, this doesn't work.

The fix here is to use two different names. Don't use the same name for two different things.

In addition, I see you have `floor1` through `floor8`. When you start naming things with numbers appended, this is a sign that you should find a better way. In most situations, you should use a list instead of numbered variable names. Here it might be more appropriate to use a `dict` since your input data has `"Floor1"` etc as keys.

For example, I would make a `dict` that holds the amount of energy used on each floor:

```
energy = {
   'Floor1': 47.1,
   'Floor2': 31.8,
    # etc...
}
```

Then I would do something like

```
for time, floors in schedule.items():
    for floor, on_or_off in floors.items():
        floor_energy = 0
        if on_or_off == 'ON':
            floor_energy = energy[floor]
        print(floor_energy)
```

Notice how I also loop over the inner dictionary here. For the purposes of this example, I just print out the result after detecting if the electricity was on or off. I leave calculating totals as an exercise for the reader. As a hint, I suggest using a dict to store the totals.

Also notice how I use more descriptive names than just `key` and `value`. The outer keys are clearly the time and the inner keys are the floors. The names I chose here can probably be improved even further. Choosing good names is hard.

Comment: Got it ok Thanks

Comment: Any chance you could show some code for recommendations/best practice?

Comment: @HenryHub Done. I didn't finish the entire exercise, but I hope this gives an idea of what I have in mind.